# Sort array by showing first the items common to another array

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am loading users with their skills:

```
let users: Observable<UserModel[]> this.userService.getOpen().pipe(

  map((payload: Payload<UserResponse[]>) => 

  payload.result.map((response: UserResponse) => { 

    return {
      userId: response.userId, 
      skillsNames: response.skills.map((skill: SkillModel) => skill.name)
    };

  })));
```

I need to sort the `skillsNames` showing first the ones that are common to a project.

To get the skills of a `project` I am doing the following:

```
let skills: Observable<SkillModel[]> = this.skillService.getByProjectId(id).pipe(

  map((payload: Payload<SkillResponse[]>) => 

    payload.result.map((response: SkillResponse) => { 

      return {
        skillId: response.skillId, 
        name: response.name
      };

    })));
```

I can also do the matching between user's `SkillModel` and project's `SkillModel` by `skillId` but getting the names in the end.

How to do this?

**Update**

I am adding an example to better explain what I am looking for:

```
let users = [
  { 
    userId: 1,
    skills: [
      { Id: 1, name: 'Javascript' },
      { Id: 2, name: 'CSS' }
    ]
  },
  { 
    userId: 2,
    skills: [
      { Id: 1, name: 'Javascript' },
      { Id: 2, name: 'CSS' }
      { Id: 3, name: 'C#' }
    ]
  },
];

let project = { 
    projectId: 1,
    skills: [
      { Id: 2, name: 'CSS' },
      { Id: 3, name: 'C#' }
    ]
  },
```

So I would like to reorder each user skills so that the skills that also appear on project skills would appear first. So the users would become:

```
let users = [
  { 
    userId: 1,
    skills: [
      { Id: 2, name: 'CSS' },
      { Id: 1, name: 'Javascript' }
    ]
  },
  { 
    userId: 2,
    skills: [
      { Id: 2, name: 'CSS' }
      { Id: 3, name: 'C#' }
      { Id: 1, name: 'Javascript' }
    ]
  },
];
```

See how in both cases the skills that appear on project are moved up in each User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not really sure if I could understand, but I did this sample that could fit exactly what you need:

This code just sort all users based on how many skills they match with the project skills (array);

```
 const users = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    skillsNames: ['JAVA', 'PHP', 'RUBY', 'R']
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    skillsNames: ['LISP', 'TYPESCRIPT', 'C', 'DOTNET']
  },
  {
    userId: 3,
    skillsNames: ['C#', 'C++', 'VRAPTOR', 'R']
  },
  {
    userId: 4,
    skillsNames: ['LISP', 'RUBY', 'R', 'DOTNET']
  },
];

const skills = ['JAVA', 'PHP', 'RUBY', 'R'];



const userWithSortedSkills = users.map(u => {
   const sortedSkillsName = u.skillsNames.sort(name => {
       return skills.lastIndexOf(name) ? 1 : -1;     
   });

   u.skillsNames = sortedSkillsName;

   return u;
});

console.log(userWithSortedSkills);
```

Comment: Not quite ... I added a data example to better explain what I am looking for ...

Comment: I just updated! Well now its look like what you need